# List bullet moved to the right when floats applied inside list position in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

http://szczotka.net/formularz/
My list numbers in #kwestionariusz are moved to the right in chrome.
Inside I have two floated spans and span floated left goes outside the list item.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your elements' `<span class="floatLeft">` CSS:

Remove `float: left;` and use `display: inline-block;`. I tried this in Chrome's element inspector and it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. If I remove `float: left` then list numbers are ok.